# how many maximum number of row can fetch from mysql using php mysql for mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("select * from emp");
// emp table contain 10000 records
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
     echo fetch[0];
}
/* how many record i can get easily from local mysql server and from localhost as well */
?>
```

If emp table contain 10000 records, how many record i can get easily from local mysql server and from localhost as well.

Comment: Be aware that the old mysql_* extension which you're using is deprecated in version 5.5 of PHP (the current version) and is being removed from version 7 (the next version). You need migrate over to using either the mysqli_* extension or PDO

Comment: Your question is a tad confusing, do you want to know the AMOUNT of rows you can fetch? Or do you want to know how you can limit / sort what rows you get?

Comment: There should be not limit. The limits depends on the hardware of the server, the server settings, php settings and the client (running tousand of rows can slow down and make your browser crash).

Comment: @Epodax I want Max Limit of rows for a single query execution in PHP.
If suppose a table contain 10,000 of rows i want to compare data value randomly than it will terminate in between not fully execute, might be it requires some configuration to get that 10,000 of data or it there any limit.

Comment: Then it's as Yuri said, the limit will be according to your hardware and server settings.